# useStore() method always leading to undefined value within components

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vuex4

I am using Vue3/Vuex 4/TypeScript.

I am trying to access my typed store from within my component (`App.vue`).

Whenever I set `const store = useStore()`, `store` will always return as `undefined`

As far as I can tell, I've followed the official [Vuex 4 TypeScript Support Documentation](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html) verbatim.

**app.ts**

```
import { createApp, Component } from "vue"
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router"
import { store, key } from "./store/store"
import App from "./pages/App.vue"
import Home from "./pages/Home.vue"
import Lookup from "./pages/Lookup.vue"

const About = { template: "<div>About</div>" }

const routes = [
  { path: "/", name: "home", component: Home as Component },
  { path: "/about", name: "about", component: About },
  { path: "/lookup", name: "lookup", component: Lookup as Component },
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
})

createApp(App).use(router, store, key).mount("#app")

export default router
```

**store.ts**

```
import { InjectionKey } from 'vue'
import { createStore, useStore as baseUseStore, Store } from 'vuex'

export interface State {
  count: number
}

export const key: InjectionKey<Store<State>> = Symbol()

export const store = createStore<State>({
  state: {
    count: 0
  }
})

// define your own `useStore` composition function
export function useStore () {
  return baseUseStore(key)
}
```

**App.vue**

```
<script lang="ts">
import { useStore } from '../store/store'
export default {
  setup(): { [key: string]: unknown } {
    const foo = "bar"

    const store = useStore()
    
    console.log(store)
    console.log(store.state.count)

    return { foo }
  },
}
</script>
```

store is always returning as undefined, here's my console messages from FireFox

```
[Vue warn]: injection "Symbol()" not found. 
  at <App> app.js:5871:17
undefined app.js:16779:13
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of setup function 
  at <App> app.js:5871:17
Uncaught TypeError: store is undefined
    setup http://boilerplate.local/js/app.js:16780
    callWithErrorHandling http://boilerplate.local/js/app.js:5987
    setupStatefulComponent http://boilerplate.local/js/app.js:12359
    setupComponent http://boilerplate.local/js/app.js:12320
    mountComponent http://boilerplate.local/js/app.js:10027
    processComponent http://boilerplate.local/js/app.js:10003
    patch http://boilerplate.local/js/app.js:9621
    render http://boilerplate.local/js/app.js:10704
    mount http://boilerplate.local/js/app.js:8907
    mount http://boilerplate.local/js/app.js:14290
    <anonymous> http://boilerplate.local/js/app.js:23012
    <anonymous> http://boilerplate.local/js/app.js:23014
    <anonymous> http://boilerplate.local/js/app.js:23016
```

I've tried to debug this all day but really can't narrow in on the problem. Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your syntax for installing the Vuex instance to your app is a little off. You can only install one Vue plugin to an app in each call to `use`, so combining `router, store, key` like that doesn't work. As such, Vuex isn't getting installed at all.

To fix, change this line:

```
createApp(App).use(router, store, key).mount("#app")
```

to this:

```
createApp(App).use(router).use(store, key).mount("#app")
```

(`key` is just an option passed to `store`, so it does belong in the second call.)